# Missing pieces of XML data in Map<String,String>

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I've parsed a particular XML file which has repeating data using XPaths. The way I did this was by scanning the entire document and getting every value element's xpath, then I used Javax Xpath library to retrieve the data from that value element's xpath.

Here is my code:

```
public void test() throws Exception {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    File f = new File("xmlDir/INWKS941_AllSchedB_IFSP.xml");

    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    String xml = FileUtils.readFileToString(f);
    Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));

    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
    List<String> xpaths = getXPaths(stream);

    Map<String, String> mapUniques = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> multiOccurance = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    Integer count = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<xpaths.size();i++) {
        String xPathExpr = xpaths.get(i);
        count++;

        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(xPathExpr).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        Integer counter = 1;
        for(int j=0;j<nodeList.getLength();j++) {

            if(nodeList.getLength() <= 1) {
                mapUniques.put(xPathExpr, nodeList.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }

            else if(nodeList.getLength() > 1) {
                multiOccurance.put(xPathExpr, nodeList.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }

            counter++;
        }
    }

    logger.info("Here: "+Arrays.toString(multiOccurance.entrySet().toArray()));


    Iterator it = multiOccurance.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Entry pair = (Entry) it.next();
        logger.info(pair.getKey()+"="+pair.getValue());
        it.remove();
    }

    Iterator iter = mapUniques.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Entry pair = (Entry) iter.next();
        logger.info(pair.getKey()+"="+pair.getValue());
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

The output of both maps are missing the duplicated piece of data. It's just grabbing the data associated with unique xpaths. The mapUniques is for getting the values for unique xpaths but the multiOccurance map is suppose to grab data for xpaths who have multiple values. Must I somehow edit the Xpaths with multiple occurances such as /PayrollFormInfo/FormInfo[1]/ExportDataVersion/100 and /PayrollFormInfo/FormInfo[2]/ExportDataVersion/100 notice how it's the same Xpath but denotes the occurance of the data.

How can I do this?

XML document:

```
<PayrollFormInfo xmlns="http://www.irs.com/PayrollFormInfo/2004">
    <FormInfo>
        <ExportDataVersion>100</ExportDataVersion>
        <QBVersion>IFSP</QBVersion>
        <FormSetID>FSDYF</FormSetID>
        <FormID>INWKS941</FormID>
        <FormDesc>Quarterly Federal Tax Return</FormDesc>
        <FormFilingPeriod>Quarterly</FormFilingPeriod>
        <TotalsBreakoutBy>Daily</TotalsBreakoutBy>
        <BeginDate>01/01/2015</BeginDate>
        <EndDate>03/31/2015</EndDate>
        <EFYes>true</EFYes>
        <IncludeInstructionSheet>false</IncludeInstructionSheet>
    </FormInfo>
    <CompanyInfo>
        <CompanyName>PatsFedTaxSemiWeekly20144QRT_CT</CompanyName>
        <LegalName>P #a(9t)-'&amp;sFedTaxSemiWeekly2014_4QRTCT</LegalName>
        <EmployerID>507754170</EmployerID>
        <IntuitPayrollServiceID>1862684</IntuitPayrollServiceID>
        <LegalAddressLine1>Def-ault/ .String</LegalAddressLine1>
        <LegalCity>St. Louis</LegalCity>
        <LegalState>CB</LegalState>
        <LegalZip>06300-0987</LegalZip>
        <MailingAddressLine1>Default String Addr</MailingAddressLine1>
        <MailingCity>Greenwich</MailingCity>
        <MailingState>CT</MailingState>
        <MailingZip>06830</MailingZip>
        <NumberOfEmployees>2</NumberOfEmployees>
        <FWTDepositFrequency>SEMI_WEEKLY</FWTDepositFrequency>
        <ExemptFlag>false</ExemptFlag>
        <EmployerType>Contributing</EmployerType>
        <FUTAExemptFlag>false</FUTAExemptFlag>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>01/01/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>15384.62</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-10.10</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>15384.62</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-1.01</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>13076.92</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-101.00</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>1.01</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/02/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>01/02/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>15384.62</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-10.20</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>15384.62</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-1.02</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>13076.92</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-102.00</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>1.02</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <TaxItemTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>03/31/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <TaxTableID>200</TaxTableID>
            <TotalWagesAndTips>0.00</TotalWagesAndTips>
            <TaxableWagesAndTips>164615.44</TaxableWagesAndTips>
            <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
        </TaxItemTotals>
        <PaymentInfo>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/14/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>01/16/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <Amount>953.86</Amount>
            <PaymentDate>04/03/2015</PaymentDate>
        </PaymentInfo>
        <EmpsWorked>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>3/12/2015</TestDate>
            <NumEmps>2</NumEmps>
        </EmpsWorked>
        <EmpSummary>
            <EmployeeID>4514230</EmployeeID>
            <FirstName>JillCT</FirstName>
            <MiddleInitial>S</MiddleInitial>
            <LastName>Taylor</LastName>
            <SSN>150-86-6794</SSN>
            <IsStatutory>false</IsStatutory>
            <HasPensionPlan>false</HasPensionPlan>
            <EmployeeType>REGULAR</EmployeeType>
        </EmpSummary>
        <EmpSummary>
            <EmployeeID>4514229</EmployeeID>
            <FirstName>JoseCT</FirstName>
            <MiddleInitial>S</MiddleInitial>
            <LastName>George</LastName>
            <SSN>792-93-6215</SSN>
            <IsStatutory>false</IsStatutory>
            <HasPensionPlan>false</HasPensionPlan>
            <EmployeeType>REGULAR</EmployeeType>
        </EmpSummary>
        <FederalReturnType>941</FederalReturnType>
    </CompanyInfo>
    <EmployeeInfo>
        <EmployeeType>REGULAR</EmployeeType>
        <EmployeeID>4514230</EmployeeID>
        <FirstName>JillCT</FirstName>
        <MiddleInitial>S</MiddleInitial>
        <LastName>Taylor</LastName>
        <SSN>150-86-6794</SSN>
        <HireDate>10/09/2009</HireDate>
        <IsStatutory>false</IsStatutory>
        <HasPensionPlan>false</HasPensionPlan>
        <NumberOfExemptions>0</NumberOfExemptions>
        <StateLived>CT</StateLived>
        <StateWorked>CT</StateWorked>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <AddressLine1>123 default St.</AddressLine1>
        <City>Greenwich</City>
        <State>CT</State>
        <ZipCode>06830</ZipCode>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>01/31/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>49269.21</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-3054.69</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>50769.24</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-736.16</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>46153.84</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-14242.77</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>02/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>02/28/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>15384.62</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-953.85</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>35384.62</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-513.08</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>33076.92</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-10637.87</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>03/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>03/31/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>46153.86</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-2861.54</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>196153.86</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-3654.22</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>189230.76</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-68440.64</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
    </EmployeeInfo>
    <EmployeeInfo>
        <EmployeeType>REGULAR</EmployeeType>
        <EmployeeID>4514229</EmployeeID>
        <FirstName>JoseCT</FirstName>
        <MiddleInitial>S</MiddleInitial>
        <LastName>George</LastName>
        <SSN>792-93-6215</SSN>
        <HireDate>10/09/2009</HireDate>
        <IsStatutory>false</IsStatutory>
        <HasPensionPlan>false</HasPensionPlan>
        <NumberOfExemptions>0</NumberOfExemptions>
        <StateLived>CT</StateLived>
        <StateWorked>CT</StateWorked>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
        <AddressLine1>123 default St.</AddressLine1>
        <City>Greenwich</City>
        <State>CT</State>
        <ZipCode>06830</ZipCode>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>02/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>02/28/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>15384.62</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-953.85</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>35384.62</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-513.08</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>33076.92</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-10637.87</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>01/31/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>49269.21</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-3054.69</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>50769.24</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-736.16</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>46153.84</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-14242.77</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>03/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>03/31/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>46153.86</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-2861.54</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>196153.86</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-3654.22</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>189230.76</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-68440.64</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
    </EmployeeInfo>
    <PaidPreparerInfo>
        <Signature>data:image</Signature>
        <Title>Agent in Fact</Title>
        <Date>03/15/2015</Date>
        <PrintedName>Coreen Solano</PrintedName>
        <PhoneNumber>888-927-7478</PhoneNumber>
        <FaxNumber>775-562-2657</FaxNumber>
        <FEIN>88-0146711</FEIN>
        <Address1>6884 Sierra Center Pkwy</Address1>
        <City>Reno</City>
        <State>NV</State>
        <Zip>89511</Zip>
        <FirmName>Computing Resources Inc</FirmName>
        <EmailAddress>tax_eservice@irs.com</EmailAddress>
    </PaidPreparerInfo>
</PayrollFormInfo>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my code for obtaining XPath for the value nodes:

```
public List<String> getXPaths ( InputStream stream ) throws ParserException {

    Document document = XMLUtils.getDocument(  stream );

    return getXPaths( document.getDocumentElement() );
}



public List<String> getXPaths ( Node node ) {

    List<String> xpaths = iterate( node, "");

    return xpaths;
}


public List<String> iterate ( Node node, String parentPath )  {

    List<String> xpaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    if ( node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) {

        Element element = ( Element ) node;
        parentPath = parentPath + "/" +  element.getTagName();

        for ( int nIndex = 0; nIndex<node.getChildNodes().getLength(); nIndex++ ) {
            xpaths.addAll( iterate(node.getChildNodes().item(nIndex) , parentPath ) ) ;
        }
    }
    else if ( node.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ) {
        if (  node.getTextContent().trim().length() !=0 ) {
            logger.debug("XPath found : " + parentPath );
            xpaths.add( parentPath );
        }
    }
    else {
        logger.debug("Unknown node type for : " + node.getNodeName());
    }
    return xpaths;
}
```

Here's my custom XMLUtils class:

```
public class XMLUtils {

    public static Document getDocument( InputStream stream ) throws ParserException {

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse( stream );

            return doc;
        }
        catch ( Exception e) {
            throw new ParserException( e.getMessage() );
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values in the multiOccurrance map are being overwritten each time through the inner loop. I am not sure how you want to collect old values and new but here would be one option:

```
for (int j = 0; j < nodeList.getLength(); j++) {
    if (nodeList.getLength() <= 1) {
        mapUniques.put(xPathExpr, nodeList.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    } else {
        String old = multiOccurance.get(xPathExpr);
        if (old == null) {
            old = "";
        }
        multiOccurance.put(xPathExpr,
                old + " "
                + nodeList.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Another approach is to try to make the keys unique, if the keys are unique you won't have to append the old values:

```
for (int j = 0; j < nodeList.getLength(); j++) {
    if (nodeList.getLength() <= 1) {
        mapUniques.put(xPathExpr, nodeList.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    } else {
        String nodePath = "";
        Node n = nodeList.item(j);
        while(n  != null) {
            int nodenum = 0;
            Node sib = n.getPreviousSibling();
            while(sib != null) {
                nodenum++;
                sib = sib.getPreviousSibling();
            }
            nodePath = n.getNodeName()+"["+nodenum+"]/"+nodePath;
            n = n.getParentNode();
        }
        multiOccurance.put(nodePath,
                 nodeList.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: I see, but how can I attribute the values to indiviual xpaths? In your solution, the values are all for one key. Example: /PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/EmpsWorked/TestDate= 1/12/2015 2/12/2015 3/12/2015 1/12/2015 2/12/2015 3/12/2015 1/12/2015 etc... How can I make it so it is /PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/EmpsWorked[1]/TestDate=1/12/2015 and /PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/EmpsWorked[2]/TestDate=2/12/2015 etc..

Comment: Added another approach to the answer. I am not sure I can get the exact xpath expression for each value or that there necessarily is one. Maybe this will get you started.

Comment: Thank you, this definitly helps. I've added my code for obtaining xpaths for any xml document if you are interested

Comment: I guess the issue with my implementation of getting the XPaths is that it does not insert the [instance number] for the xpaths who have multiple values in different places in the document